# Qt5 - Force stay on top during fullscreen

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, user32

Trying to write an application using Qt that would put a watermark on the screen.
Using below flags allowed me to make my window to appear above everything except in situations where user is using Fullscreen mode in Windows Photos.

```
self.setWindowFlags(
        Qt.WindowTransparentForInput | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint |
        Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Tool | Qt.MaximizeUsingFullscreenGeometryHint)
```

Is there a possibility of forcing window to stay on top in aforementioned case? i.e. using user32 without rewriting everything for different framework.

Comment: There's no flag that guarantees a window stay on top of literally everything else no matter what. If there was, what would happen if two programs used it?

Comment: Well, i guess it should be decided just in order of setting this flag.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows you can draw on desktop using `gdi32` and `user32`, if watermark is all you need you can try this approach.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

from ctypes.wintypes import HDC, HWND, RECT

from ctypes import windll

GetDC = windll.user32.GetDC
ReleaseDC = windll.user32.ReleaseDC
SetTextColor = windll.gdi32.SetTextColor
DrawText = windll.user32.DrawTextW

class Watermark(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._text = None
        self._visible = False
        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.setInterval(10)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.onTimeout)
        timer.start()
        self._timer = timer
        
    def setText(self, text):
        self._text = text

    def show(self):
        self._visible = True
    
    def onTimeout(self):
        if not self._visible or self._text is None:
            return
        rect = RECT()
        hwnd = 0
        hdc = GetDC(hwnd)
        rect.left = 0
        rect.top = 0
        rect.bottom = 100
        rect.right = 100
        SetTextColor(hdc, 0x00000000)
        DT_SINGLELINE = 0x00000020
        DT_NOCLIP = 0x00000100
        DrawText(hdc, self._text, -1, rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_NOCLIP) 
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    watermark = Watermark()
    watermark.setText("This stays on top")
    watermark.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot.